# DISTINCT + другие поля MySQL

Tags: mysql

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы в выборке были другие поля? Сейчас выводится только login, а нужно вывести ещё password, city и т.д.. **GROUP BY не предлагать**!

```
SELECT DISTINCT `login`
 FROM `accounts`
WHERE `valid` = '1'
```

Если перечислять их в

```
DISTINCT `login`, `password`, `city`
```

То уникальность становится по всем трём этим полям, а мне нужна уникальность только по login, а остальные поля чтобы просто были в выборке.

Comment: *Сейчас выводится только login, а нужно вывести ещё password, city* А смысл? У одного логина три пароля и два города, выведется случайный пароль из трёх и случайный город из двух (и не факт, что эта пара будет из одной и той же записи) - и нафига могут быть нужны такие данные?

Comment: @Akina, а как мне например вывести в таблицу данные (table html)? Я хочу вывести нужные мне данные в таблицу, а уникальность выбрать по `login`.

Comment: А это только Вам решать, что делать в случае типа описанного... но уж никак не выводить что под руку подвернулось...

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь window functions

```
select * from (
   SELECT 
   *,
   row_number() over(partition by login order by 'password', 'city') as rowNumber
   FROM `accounts`
WHERE `valid` = '1') 
AS data 
where rowNumber = 1
```

о вернет вам уникальные подберите сортировку такую чтоб под первым стоял вам нужные логины.

Comment: Ошибка: Неизвестный оператор. (near "with" at position 0)

Comment: @ModaL Поздравляю, у Вас сервер пятой версии - кстати, эту информацию следует добавить в текст вопроса.

Comment: @ModaL изменил запрос

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '(partition by login order by 'password', 'city') as rowNumber
   FROM `accounts' на строке 4

Comment: @AzizUmarov И оконные функции, и CTE - недоступны в пятёрке.

Comment: Идея использовать оконные функции. подправьте. У меня базы вашей нет что бы проверить.

Comment: @Akina Я извиняюсь, но про версию. Марии тут ничего не сказано.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Вопрос тегован на MySQL, да и сабж тоже. А указанные ошибки - однозначно говорят о том, что указанные конструкции не поддерживаются версией. Т.е. версия ниже восьмой. Для MariaBD - соответственно  10.1 или хуже.